# Как поменять цвет png?

Tags: photoshop

Имеется иконка png одного цвета.
Нужно просто заменить цвет на другой.
Если выбрать инструмент "Заливка", то он поменяет цвет, но проблема в том, что в иконке есть ещё прозрачные, и полупрозрачные линии, которое закрашиваются полностью и становятся непрозрачными.
Подскажите, как можно поменять цвет png со всеми оттенками?
т.е. чтобы остались все полупрозрачные оттенки, но в новом цвете
photoshop cc,2017

Comment: Уже понял, нужно выбрать "Изображение-Коррекция-Заменить цвет"